# SQL display in groups

Tags: sql

I have a table of projects which are all tagged with a lookup for the associated client and want to show the data like this:

1. Client 1

   - Project 1
   - Project 2
   - Project 3
2. Client 2

   - Project 1
   - Project 2
3. Client 3

   - Project 1
   - Project 2
   - Project 3

That way I get the projects back from my table and have them "grouped" by client.
What do you call this action? Is it nested groups or something like that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL queries cannot supply a nested result as you have laid out<sup>1</sup>. Instead, your result set has to be flat, repeating the `Client` multiple times, once for each Project.  Really in your SQL query, it is just a matter of ordering to sort the like `Client` values together: `ORDER BY client`

```
Client 1    Project 1
Client 1    Project 2
Client 1    Project 3
Client 2    Project 1
Client 2    Project 2
Client 2    Project 3
```

In your application display logic then, you only print the new `Client` when the value changes from the previous one.

#### Pseudocode:

```
# Start with empty last_client
last_client = ""
loop_over_rows

  if last_client is not equal to current_row->client
    print new row->client

  # Print all projects
  print row->project

  # Store the current client to compare on next loop
  last_client = row->client
endloop
```

<sup>1</sup> It can be done in SQL with a lot of crazy string manipulation and `UNION`, but this is a matter of presentation and really belongs in the application presentation logic rather than the SQL.

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't sure if it was done in the SQL or the application logic itself, but until I know I had to ask. Thanks for the detailed answer it's really helpful!

Answer (score 0):

If your RDBMS, which is not specified in your tags, support recursive SQL you can approximate the layout you are trying to accomplish.

The following SQL works against Teradata's data dictionary tables. The Hierarchy column is offset based on depth of the database in the ownership chain. From there you should be able to take the concept and apply it to your situation.

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte (DatabaseName, Path, Parent, Level) AS
 (
  SELECT TRIM(DatabaseName)
         ,DatabaseName(VARCHAR(600))
         ,TRIM(DatabaseName)
         ,0 (BYTEINT)
  FROM   DBC.Databases d
  WHERE  DatabaseName = 'DBC'

  UNION ALL

  SELECT TRIM(d.DatabaseName)
         ,cte.Path || '.' || TRIM(d.DatabaseName)
         ,cte.Path
         ,Level + 1
  FROM   DBC.Databases d
         ,cte
  WHERE  d.OwnerName = cte.DatabaseName
  AND    d.DatabaseName <> d.OwnerName
  AND    Level < 20
 )
SELECT Level
     , SUBSTRING(CAST('' AS CHAR(60)) FROM 1 FOR Level * 2)  || DatabaseName AS Hierarchy
     , Path
     , Parent
FROM   cte
ORDER BY Path;
```